# ELF files and additional symbols

Tags: linux, glibc, elf

I'm reading about ELF file format and I've noticed that a small hello world test program written in C++ contains some additional initialization in the `_start` symbol:

```
0000000000400770 <_start>:
...
      40077f:       49 c7 c0 60 09 40 00    mov    $0x400960,%r8
      400786:       48 c7 c1 f0 08 40 00    mov    $0x4008f0,%rcx
      40078d:       48 c7 c7 5d 08 40 00    mov    $0x40085d,%rdi
...
```

`40077f` is `__libc_csu_fini`.

`4008f0` is `__libc_csu_init`.

`40085d` is `main`.

Shouldn't it just be `_start` to `main`? Why not? What would happen if I just removed both of the calls to `40077f` and `40008f0` and replaced with `nop`? Basically, what is the significance of requiring libc?

Comment: Take a look here: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [glibc source code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/elf-init.c;h=4daf673e67cf771fa888a379799e20bcbf607596;hb=HEAD#l67):

```
/* These functions are passed to __libc_start_main by the startup code.
   These get statically linked into each program.  For dynamically linked
   programs, this module will come from libc_nonshared.a and differs from
   the libc.a module in that it doesn't call the preinit array.  */


void
__libc_csu_init (int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
  /* For dynamically linked executables the preinit array is executed by
     the dynamic linker (before initializing any shared object).  */

#ifndef LIBC_NONSHARED
  /* For static executables, preinit happens right before init.  */
  {
    const size_t size = __preinit_array_end - __preinit_array_start;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      (*__preinit_array_start [i]) (argc, argv, envp);
  }
#endif

#ifndef NO_INITFINI
  _init ();
#endif

  const size_t size = __init_array_end - __init_array_start;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
      (*__init_array_start [i]) (argc, argv, envp);
}

/* This function should not be used anymore.  We run the executable's
   destructor now just like any other.  We cannot remove the function,
   though.  */
void
__libc_csu_fini (void)
{
#ifndef LIBC_NONSHARED
  size_t i = __fini_array_end - __fini_array_start;
  while (i-- > 0)
    (*__fini_array_start [i]) ();

# ifndef NO_INITFINI
  _fini ();
# endif
#endif
}
```

This allow library initialization code to run. Libraries that are linked in to the program can tag functions with `__attribute__((constructor))` in gcc, and this mechanism will run those functions before `main`, allowing libraries to initialize themselves before the program start.